# How to use a single table for multiple users

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I want to create a database which has a table named `warehouse` which contains the details of each product. I have another table named `users`. At present there are 2 users in the `users` table - **ABC** and **DEF**.
My main question is user ABC has it's own warehouse and so for user DEF. How can I use the `warehouse` table for 2 or more different users ?

Comment: Add a `userid` column to `warehouse` which is a foreign key to the `id` value in `users`

Answer (score 3):

***One to one***

If one user own only one warehouse then you should add **user_id** column in warehouse table. then reference the user_id from user table via foreign key.

***One to many***

if multiple user owns an warehouse then you should add **warehouse** column in user table. then reference the warehouse from warehouse table via foreign key.

***Many to Many***

if an user owns multiple warehouse and and warehouse has multiple owner then you should add a **table like warehouse_users** and add keep **warehouse and user_id**.